# Query Builder OR and IS NULL in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder, laravel-9, laravel-query-builder

I have a query like this

```
SELECT ruangans.nama_ruangan, beds.id AS idBed, beds.nomor_bed, pasiens.nama, pasiens.status
FROM `beds` JOIN ruangans ON beds.id_ruangan = ruangans.id
LEFT JOIN pasiens ON beds.id = pasiens.id_bed
WHERE pasiens.status != 'Sudah Rawat Inap' OR pasiens.status IS NULL;
```

I'm still new in Laravel Query Builder, my question is how to convert the SQL query to Query Builder, especially at the OR and IS NULL operation. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::table("beds")
->join("ruangans", "beds.id_ruangan", "=", "ruangans.id")
->leftJoin("pasiens", "beds.id", "=", "pasiens.id_bed")
->select("ruangans.nama_ruangan", "beds.id as idbed", "beds.nomor_bed", "pasiens.nama", "pasiens.status")
->where("pasiens.status", "!=", 'Sudah Rawat Inap')
->orWhereNull("pasiens.status")
->get();
```

Laravel offers several variation of where methods to add "where" clauses to your queries. You can find them here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#basic-where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$query = DB::table('beds')
    ->join('ruangans', 'beds.id_ruangan', '=', 'ruangans.id')
    ->leftJoin('pasiens', 'beds.id', '=', 'pasiens.id_bed')
    ->select(
        'ruangans.nama_ruangan',
        'beds.id AS idBed',
        'beds.nomor_bed',
        'pasiens.nama',
        'pasiens.status'
    )
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('pasiens.status', '!=', 'Sudah Rawat Inap')
              ->orWhereNull('pasiens.status');
    })
    ->get();
```

As you know we use `where` to filter the data. In this, I've used a sub-query mechanism to filter the data within the same `pasiens` table.

---

Read more about [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries)